Real Valued 2D fourier series over a complex domain (and 2D manifold)?
This answer does a great job of explaining the fourier basis for $\mathbb{R}^2$, however, the answer assumes a square domain.
Is it possible to generalise the answer to mor complicated domains? Like a circle, or an arbitrary blob enclosed by a simple curve?
And then, in a more complicated setting, can they be generalized to arbitrary 2-manifolds?  Say, a Torus?
